Transposed group representation matrix
Following the group representation chapter in Riley, Hobson and Bence (RHB) textbook, I am really confused by the representative matrix, as I cannot understand why we take the transpose of a matrix representing the action of a group. The order of elements in this book is defined as:
Given two elements $X, Y$ of a group, $Z=XY$ means first applying $Y$ and then applying $X$ to the result.
When defining the representative matrix, given a basis vector $\textrm{u}=(u_1,...,u_n)^\textrm{T}$, the action of $X$ on $u_i$ gives $u_i'=Xu_i$ and such a matrix $\textrm{M}(X)$ makes
$$\textrm{u}'=\textrm{M}(X)\textrm{u} \tag{1}\label{eq}$$
So far it's all fine, then by the book, since the order of group elements $Z=XY$ means $Y$ first and then $X$, the representative matrices $\textrm{D}(X)$ may follow the same convection and defined as the transpose of $\textrm{M}(X)$ as $\textrm{D}(X)=\textrm{M}^\textrm{T}(X)$, so Eq.\eqref{eq} becomes
$$\textrm{u}'=\textrm{D}^\textrm{T}(X)\textrm{u}$$
My confusion is that it's apparently left matrix multiplication, and thus
$$\textrm{M}(Z)\textrm{u}=\textrm{M}(X)\textrm{M}(Y)\textrm{u}$$
would naturally start with $Y$, why bother a transpose, which in this case is even wrong? I could understand if it's right multiplication, transpose is required, but, again, apparently it's doing left multiplication here. What makes me even more confusing is its footnote on page 1079:

An alternative procedure in which a row vector is used as the basis vector is possible. Defining
equations of the form $\textrm{u}^\textrm{T}X=\textrm{u}^\textrm{T}\textrm{D}(X)$ are used, and no additional transpositions are needed to
define the representative matrices. However, row-matrix equations are cumbersome to write out
and in all other parts of this book we have adopted the convention of writing operators (here the
group element) to the left of the object on which they operate (here the basis vector).

which seems totally opposite to me: transpose should be required for right multiplication, not the left one. I have seen another related answer but it seems to me that transpose is still only required for right group action. I can hardly believe the author would make such a mistake here, so where am I wrong?

I think the confusion may be between the action on a vector space vs the action on coordinates with respect to a basis. In effect, once you choose a basis the coordinates are elements of the dual space.
If you take any finite dimensional vector space $V$ and choose a basis $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ then there is an isomorphism $\varphi\colon V\to V^*$ to its dual space which sends $v_i$ to the linear mapping $v_i^*\colon V\to F$ to the ground field with $v_i^*(v_j)=1$ if $j=i$ and $0$ otherwise. If you have a linear mapping $\theta\colon V\to V$ where $\theta(v_j)=\sum_ia_{i,j}v_i$ then the matrix transforming the column vector $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)^T$ associated with the vector $\sum_jx_jv_j$ is the one whose $i,j$ entry is $a_{i,j}$ but this is the transpose of the matrix that transforms the column vector of basis vectors $(v_1,\ldots,v_n)^T$.
To add to the confusion, when $V=F^n$ thought of as consisting of column vectors it is usual to take the standard basis consisting of the $e_i$. But then it is common to identify $V^*$ with the space of row vectors so $e_i^*$ is the row vector with $0$s except for a $1$ in the $i$-th place. The dual pairing $V^*\times V\to F$ is just multiplication of row vectors onto column vectors.
In representation theory, the action of a group $G$ on $V$ gives rise to the contragredient action on $V^*$. This is defined taking for $g\in G$ and $f\in V^*$ the product $g\cdot f$ to mean the functional satisfying $(g\cdot f)(v)=f(g^{-1}v)$. If we choose an invariant inner product and an orthonormal to make the representation via orthogonal matrices at the $(-)^{-1}$ becomes a $(-)^T$ at the matrix level. Over $\mathbb{C}$ we would use use unitary matrices so transpose would become hermitian conjugate.
I hope that helps!

Sorry it took me some time to understand what you are saying, and I feel like this is not the key point of my question, which is why we have to use the transpose of $M$ rather than direcly using $M$. According to the book, I think it's not related to the dual space $V^*$, as all the matrices here are representations of elements of the group.

The main question is why the transpose is required with left multiplication and $Z=XY$. According to the book:
"It may seem natural to use the matrix $M(X)$ so generated as the representative
matrix of the element $X$; in fact, because we have already chosen the convention
whereby $Z = XY$ implies that the effect of applying element $Z$ is the same as that
of first applying $Y$ and then applying $X$ to the result, one further step has to be
taken."

"So that the representative matrices $D(X)$ may follow the same convention,
i.e. $D(Z) = D(X)D(Y)$ and at the same time respect the normal rules of matrix multiplication, it is necessary to take the transpose of $M(X)$ as the representative matrix $D(X)$. Explicitly $D(X) = MT(X)$"
